# Java run multiple threads from for loop with different names

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop

I am trying to start a variable number of threads within a for loop and want to name the threads prime1, prime2, [...].

The `PrimeFinderThread` Class extends from Thread.

```
[...]

    for (int i = 0; i <= numberThreads; i++) {
         PrimeFinderThread ("prime" + i) = new PrimeFinderThread (lowerBoundary, interval); 
    }

[...]
```

I am getting the error:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable.

from `("prime" + i)`

What is a possible soloution to start **X** Threads with a seperate name for each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Thread[] threads = new PrimeFinderThread[numberThreads];
for (int i = 0; i < numberThreads; i++) {
    threads[i] = new PrimeFinderThread (lowerBoundary, interval);
    threads[i].setName("prime" + i);
    threads[i].start();
}
```

It sets the name via the `setName`-method and then starts each thread via a call to `start`.

However, it is probably easier to make the constructor of `PrimeFinderThread` take an extra argument which is the `name` and invoke the super class constructor.

```
public PrimeFinderThread (String name, int lowerBoundary, int interval) {
    super(name); // instead of setName
    // Do the other stuff
}
```

IMO, an even better approach is to *not* extend the `Thread` class but rather provide a `Runnable`, preferably with some kind of `ExecutorService` - check e.g. the [Executors JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) or the [concurrency trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) from the Oracle website.

Comment: See p. 464 chapter "Callable, Executors, ExecutorService, ThreadPool, and Future" in the book "Oracle Certified professional Java SE 7 programmer exams 1z0-804 and 1z0-805. It has a good example on Executors and ThreadPools. :)

Answer (score 2):

For an assignment in Java you cannot specify additional parameters on the left hand side of the `=` operator. So `PrimeFinderThread ("prime" + i)` is and will stay invalid.

Instead you should simply define an additional parameter for your constructor, and pass that to the parent class constructor using the `super` keyword construct.

You should assign the created threads to some variable

```
PrimeFinderThread[] threads = new PrimeFinderThread[numberThreads];
for (int i = 0; i < numberThreads; i++) {
    threads[i] = new PrimeFinderThread ("prime" + (i+1), lowerBoundary, interval); 
    threads[i].start();
}
```

As for setting the name of each thread, that depends on what constructors your PrimeFinderThread class has. You can pass the thread name to the constructor of `PrimeFinderThread`, and from there, pass it to the constructor of `Thread`.

For example:

```
public PrimeFinderThread (String name, int lowerBoundary, int interval)
{
    super (name);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think that this solution is cleaner.

Comment: wrote my own answer, but I've updated yours instead. Do you agree with the changes?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead The update looks good. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify additional parameters with X in left side assignment in Java.
To give name to your threads you can call super(threadName) from the sub class of thread or thread.setName("threadName") can be used.

```
public class ThreadSubClass extends Thread{

    public ThreadSubClass(String threadName){
        super(threadName);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Entering : " + getName());
        //do Something
    }


    public static void main(String [] args){
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            ThreadSubClass t = new ThreadSubClass("Prime"+i);
            t.start();
        }
    }

}
```